# Markdown toc extension change `paragraph` ¶ symbol

Tags: markdown, pelican

In http://pythonhosted.org/Markdown/extensions/toc.html#usage there is option of `permalink`.

1. I want to change the default symbol of `&para` to some other ASCII char.
   How to do it?
2. Change the distance of the symbol form the header?

Example:
Now I get this

```
<h3 id="title1">title1<a title="Permanent link" href="#title1" class="headerlink">¶</a></h3>
```

But I want to change the ¶ symbol to other ASCII and change its distance from header.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `MARKDOWN` [config setting](http://docs.getpelican.com/en/stable/settings.html#basic-settings) to pass config options to Markdown, including extensions. In your `pelicanconf.py` file, include the following:

```
MARKDOWN = {
    'extension_configs': {
        'markdown.extensions.toc': {'permalink': 'your replacement string here'}
    }
}
```

Stylistic changes would be done through CSS. You will likely need to modify the theme to include some CSS to add some padding to any element with the `headerlink` class. For example, to add `1em` of space to the left of the permalink, include the following rule:

```
.headerlink {
    padding-left: 1em;
}
```

For more information about Pelican themes, see the [documentation](http://docs.getpelican.com/en/stable/themes.html).